# not recognizing alias in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias

I am trying to query the following information. Without the WHERE clause, the query executes perfectly; however, when I add in the WHERE clause, I get an error with the alias "error_percentage" not being recognized. I also tried using HAVING instead of WHERE, as well as LIMIT.

How should I approach narrowing down my query using this alias I created in the SELECT clause?

```
SELECT date, ((CAST(error AS float) / CAST(success AS float)) *100) AS error_percentage
FROM daily_report
WHERE error_percentage > 1
ORDER BY error_percentage DESC;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you working with mysql, postgresql, or both,or have you misplaced the `psql` tag ?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL, but I figured the problem I am having applied to both because of order of operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column aliases (here: `error_percentage`) are not accessible before the construction of the result set. `ORDER BY` is not affected as sorting happens (necessarily) _after_the result set has been retrieved.

Use

```
SELECT agg.*
  FROM (
          SELECT date, ((CAST(error AS float) / CAST(success AS float)) *100) AS error_percentage
            FROM daily_report
        ORDER BY error_percentage DESC
       ) agg
 WHERE error_percentage > 1
     ;
```

It's more efficient and probably cleaner if you trim the result set first:

```
  SELECT agg.*
    FROM (
            SELECT date, ((CAST(error AS float) / CAST(success AS float)) *100) AS error_percentage
              FROM daily_report
         ) agg
   WHERE error_percentage > 1
ORDER BY error_percentage DESC
     ;
```

Comment: Works well, except I had to remove the semi colon after "DESC"

Comment: Yep, sorry, for that, copy-paste  typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would just replace the `where` with an expression:

```
SELECT date,
       ((CAST(error AS float) / CAST(success AS float)) *100) AS error_percentage
FROM daily_report
WHERE error > 0.01 * success
ORDER BY error_percentage DESC;
```